# For Resume parsing, how to get the heading?

Tags: php

This is my code for Resume parsing, I am not getting the heading, could anybody please tell me how to get the heading?

```
private function read_docx(){

    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    $zip = zip_open($this->filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this ?

```
 $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p><w:tc></w:tc>', " ", $content);
```

instead of

```
$content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
```